# How order results of SQL request according hierarchy level

Tags: java, sql

I the context of a Java application I am using SQLIte to persist some data. One of my SQL table has the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE containers (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, PARENT_ID INT)
```

I need to retrieve all the containers **ORDERED** by hierarchy level. I.e I want first all the containers without parent (PARENT_ID == -1), then the ones with 1 ancestor, then with 2 ancestors, etc ....

Is there any way to do that with an SQL request such as below to have a `ResultSet` object sorted in this way.

```
SELECT * from container ORDER BY (**"What to put here ???"**)
```

***Edit*** I know I can do that in Java later but I am not interested in this solution.

Comment: How looks like table of Parent_id refernce.

Comment: It's the same table !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to achieve this directly in standard SQL. Oracle has the "start with", "connect by" syntax and that supports it through "level".

Alternatively, if you can remodel your data you could instead use nested sets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: +1 for nested sets. There are a few ways to handle storing hierarchical and tree information in a SQL table; each approach requires you to do some design ahead of time and make tradeoffs to accomplish what you'd like